# Not able to run a command from different directory using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray, null, directory);

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I want to run the command in bin directory of openSSL folder through. I want to run the command from C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\ directory. And I need to execute the following command:
Openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 Message.txt

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;  
public class TestExec {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            File directory1 = new File("C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\");
            System.out.println(directory1.toString());
            String[] commandArray = {"Openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 Message.txt"};
            Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandArray, null, directory1);

    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}  
}
```

I am getting the following IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 Message.txt" (in directory "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at package1.TestExec.main(TestExec.java:10)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the working directory doesn't mean that java will look for the executable in that directory. It is just sets to current directory for the executable.

I'm not sure of the exact behaviour on windows regarding the PATH environment variable, but have at what it is currently set to...

Anyway, I'd try using this instead

```
String[] commandArray = {"C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\Openssl\\Openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 Message.txt"};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The follopwing changes worked:String cmd = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out Record1.sha1 message.txt";